# BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::get does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'd start a new laravel project, and want to make a controller called `ProductController` using Artisan, but it ends up with an error

> “BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::get does not exist.“

I'm using laravel 6.0

routes:

```php
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index');
```

Command used:

```sh
php artisan make:controller ProductController
```

Comment: Share the code inside `ProductController`

Comment: hi bro, I just want to create it through PHP artisan and it ends up with error, so the file is haven't be created bro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the `Route` facade instead of `Illuminate\Routing\Route`

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help bro, after changed its worked now. default is Illuminate\Routing\Route. I'm even not so understand what this code function, cause im just a newbie, just start on learning.

Comment: sure bro, just now just wait the available time to click the accept button. but bro can I ask whats the difference of both of that code? if you dont mind to explaint to me :)

Comment: The `Illuminate\Routing\Route` is used internally by the framework as a routing engine, it resolves URLs and parses the Controllers and their actions, while the Support Facade is meant to be used by the developer to perform redirects for example, it's the same as calling the `route()` helper function

Answer (score 0):

you maybe
use
`href="{{route('--')}}"`
instead of
`href="{{url('---')}}"`
for routing in your blade , just change it to `href="{{url('---')}}"`